# Hash not found while visualizing

Tags: drake-r-package

In my active project, I find this error today. The targets are up to date. However the visualization fails.

```r
> config <- drake_config(plan)
> outdated(config)
character(0)
> vis_drake_graph(config, build_times = "build", targets_only = T)
Error: hash 'dd9f951f9452251b' not found
> sankey_drake_graph(config)
Error: hash 'dd9f951f9452251b' not found
```

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I was using the bleeding edge `drake` from `GitHub`. Then I downgraded to CRAN when I saw this error. Reinstalling bleeding edge version fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you think it had to do with the transition mid-project, or is there something wrong with CRAN `drake` itself?

Comment: Just had this now, and I ran the `make(plan)` and then could do the `vis_drake_graph(drake_config(plan))' afterwards. I don't think it's an issue with the CRAN version, I suspect it might just be something to do with drake picking up the hashes where they were created with newer versions of drake. It's hard to make things 'forward' compatible.